# javafx: Bindings not working as expected

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to have a property `total` which is obtained by multiplying two properties together, namely `currentPrice` and `volumeHeld`, where `currentPrice` is actually obtained by downloading google finance stock price every 10 secs. And it automatically updates every 10 seconds.

Now the `getCurrentPrice()` is initialized at `0`, as shown in the code. 10 seconds later, it picks up a new value and this all works fine.

But in the binding method below, the `total` is not automatically updated when the `currentPrice` property has changed.

```
totalBinding = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
        System.out.println("current price: " + getCurrentPrice() + "vol held: " + getVolumeHeld());
        return getCurrentPrice() * getVolumeHeld();
    });

   total.bind(totalBinding);
```

**Question:** I discovered that within the `createDoubleBinding` statement above, the `getCurrentPrice()` has a value of 0 (as mentioned above) and when its value is changed, the change is NOT propagated in the `total` property. By that I mean the `total` property is not able to pick up the new value from `getCurrentPrice()` even when the current price has changed.

So the problem is two-fold but I am guessing the solutions for both of my questions below will be similar if not exactly the same:

1. How can I fix the problem mentioned above?
2. Later on, I will be binding this `total` property to another property to work out the total of the `total` property for all `Trade` objects). This fails miserably and it is always equal to 0. **This method is written in a different class, i.e. not in the Trade class.**

**UPDATE:**

Code shown below:

```
class SummaryofTrade{
    ...     
    sumOfTotals = new ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper();
    sumOfTotalsBinding = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
        double sum = 0;
        for(Trade t : this.observableListOfTrades){
            sum += t.getTotal();
        }
        return sum;         
    }, total);     // I cannot put "total" as a second parameter, as it is a property that resides in the Trade class , not this class.
    sumOfTotals.bind(sumOfTotalsBinding);
    ...
}
```

The error log message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    total cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Please note that the `sumOfTotalsBinding` and `sumOfTotals` live in another class.

Code for Trade object below:

```
class Trade{
      ...
      private final ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper total;
      private final ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper currentPrice;
      private DoubleProperty volumeHeld;
      public DoubleBinding totalBinding;



      private final ScheduledService<Number> priceService = new ScheduledService<Number>() {
        @Override
        public Task<Number> createTask(){
            return new Task<Number>() {
                @Override
                public Number call() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
                    return getCurrentPriceFromGoogle();
                }
            };
        }
       };

    public Trade(){
       ...
       priceService.setPeriod(Duration.seconds(10));
        priceService.setOnFailed(e -> priceService.getException().printStackTrace());
        this.currentPrice   = new ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper(0);
        this.currentPrice.bind(priceService.lastValueProperty());
        startMonitoring();
        this.total          = new ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper();
        DoubleBinding totalBinding = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() ->
          getCurrentPrice() * getVolumeHeld(),
          currentPriceProperty(), volumeHeldProperty());                
       total.bind(totalBinding);
     }


        // volume held
    public double getVolumeHeld(){
        return this.volumeHeld.get();
    }

    public DoubleProperty volumeHeldProperty(){
        return this.volumeHeld;
    }

    public void setVolumeHeld(double volumeHeld){
        this.volumeHeld.set(volumeHeld);
    }

        // multi-threading
    public final void startMonitoring() {
         priceService.restart();
    }

    public final void stopMonitoring() {
        priceService.cancel();
    }

        public ReadOnlyDoubleProperty currentPriceProperty(){
         return this.currentPrice.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

    public final double getCurrentPrice(){
        return currentPriceProperty().get();
    }

        // total
    public final Double getTotal(){
        return totalProperty().getValue();
    }

    public ReadOnlyDoubleProperty totalProperty(){
        return this.total;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 9/15/2015:**

I am trying to elaborate my problem in a logical way here. Let me know if this does not make sense. Thanks.

First, in the `Trade class` above (please note the code above has been updated and **specified the property dependency**), each Trade object contains a `total` property, which is the product of `currentPrice` and `VolumeHeld`. If the user manually edit the values of current price and volume held. The `total` property will be updated automatically.

Now, I have an ObservableList of Trade objects, each of them has a `total` property. My goal is to sum up the the `total` property of each Trade object in the observable list and bind the sum to a variable called `sumOfTotals`. This is done in a class called `SummaryOfTrade`. And whenever the `total` property of any one of the Trades in the Observable list changes, the `sumOfTotals` property should also change automatically.

```
class SummaryofTrade{
    ...     
    // within constructor, we have
    sumOfTotals = new ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper();
    sumOfTotalsBinding = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
        double sum = 0;
        for(Trade t : this.observableListOfTrades){
            sum += t.getTotal();
        }
        return sum;         
    }, totalProperty());    
    sumOfTotals.bind(sumOfTotalsBinding);
    ...
}
```

This is where the problem comes in. Eclipse is saying that it does not recognise the Trade object's property,`totalProperty`. Error message shown below.

The error log message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method totalProperty() is undefined for the type SummaryOfTrade
```

I have specified the property dependency already yet Eclipse is throwing an error. How should I resolve this?

Comment: It's not at all clear why the answer from @AlmasB doesn't answer this question (in particular, which class the properties are defined in makes no difference at all to how you write the binding). The values of your binding remained at zero because you didn't specify the dependencies in the binding. If you fix it as in that answer, it should now work. Perhaps you can update with a [MCVE] to show what the remaining issues are?

Comment: From above, I did specify the second parameter `total` in the `createDoubleBinding` statement, i.e. the dependencies in the binding, but eclipse does not recognize it. The error is that the `total property` does not live in the `SummaryOfTrade` class, so I could not refer to it. If this is still confusing, I will re-update it again tonight.

Comment: @James_D please see update and let me know if it does not make sense. Thanks

Comment: Well you can hardly just write `totalProperty()` there and somehow expect the compiler to magically know you want it to observe all the `totalProperty()`s of all the items in the list. The compiler is not clairvoyant. You have to explicitly make that happen.

Comment: In this case, how should I tackle it ?

Comment: Bind to *each* `totalProperty()`, or create a list that is invalidated if any of the `totalProperty()`s change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an `ObservableList<Trade>`, where each `Trade` object has an observable `totalProperty()`. Your `sumOfTotals` need to be updated when either the content of that list change, or when any of the individual `totalProperty()`s belonging to any of the elements change.

You can do this by hand:

```
DoubleBinding sumOfTotalsBinding = new DoubleBinding() {

    {
        bind(observableListOfTrades);
        observableListOfTrades.forEach(trade -> bind(trade.totalProperty());
        observableListOfTrades.addListener((Change<? extends Trade> change) -> {
            while (change.next()) {
                if (change.wasAdded()) {
                    change.getAddedSubList().forEach(trade -> bind(trade.totalProperty()));
                }
                if (change.wasRemoved()) {
                    change.getRemoved().forEach(trade -> unbind(trade.totalProperty()));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public double computeValue() {
        return observableListOfTrades.stream().collect(Collectors.summingDouble(Trade::getTotal));
    }
};
```

Or, you can create your list with an [extractor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList-javafx.util.Callback-). This will cause the list to fire update notifications (thereby labeling it as invalid) when any of the specified properties belonging to the elements change:

```
ObservableList<Trade> observableListOfTrades = 
    FXCollections.observableArrayList(trade -> new Observable[] { trade.totalProperty() });
```

and then you can just do

```
sumOfTotals.bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() ->
    observableListOfTrades.stream().collect(Collectors.summingDouble(Trade::getTotal)),
    observableListOfTrades);
```

since now binding just to the `observableListOfTrades` will cause recomputation when any of the individual totals change.

Here's an SSCCE:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.DoubleBinding;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringWrapper;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.converter.DoubleStringConverter;
import javafx.util.converter.IntegerStringConverter;

public class TradeTableExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Trade> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setEditable(true);
        TableColumn<Trade, String> nameCol = column("Name", trade -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(trade.getName()));
        TableColumn<Trade, Integer> volumeCol = column("Volume", t -> t.volumeProperty().asObject());
        TableColumn<Trade, Double> priceCol = column("Price", t -> t.priceProperty().asObject());
        TableColumn<Trade, Number> totalCol = column("Total", Trade::totalProperty);

        volumeCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new IntegerStringConverter()));
        priceCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new DoubleStringConverter()));

        table.getColumns().addAll(Arrays.asList(nameCol, volumeCol, priceCol, totalCol));

        ObservableList<Trade> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(trade -> new Observable[] {trade.totalProperty()});

        DoubleBinding grandTotal = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> 
            data.stream().collect(Collectors.summingDouble(Trade::getTotal)),
            data);

        data.addAll(createData());
        table.setItems(data);

        Label totalLabel = new Label();
        totalLabel.textProperty().bind(grandTotal.asString("Total: %,.2f"));

        TextField nameField = new TextField();
        TextField volumeField = new TextField("0");
        TextField priceField = new TextField("0.00");

        Button add = new Button("Add");
        add.setOnAction(e -> {
            data.add(
                new Trade(nameField.getText(), 
                        Integer.parseInt(volumeField.getText()), 
                        Double.parseDouble(priceField.getText())));
            nameField.setText("");
            volumeField.setText("0");
            priceField.setText("0.00");
        });

        Button delete = new Button("Delete");
        delete.setOnAction(e -> data.remove(table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()));
        delete.disableProperty().bind(table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().isNull());

        HBox buttons = new HBox(5, add, delete);

        GridPane controls = new GridPane();
        controls.addRow(0, new Label("Name:"), nameField);
        controls.addRow(1, new Label("Volume:"), volumeField);
        controls.addRow(2, new Label("Price:"), priceField);
        controls.add(buttons, 0, 3, 2, 1);
        controls.add(totalLabel, 0, 4, 2, 1);

        ColumnConstraints leftCol = new ColumnConstraints();
        leftCol.setHalignment(HPos.RIGHT);
        ColumnConstraints rightCol = new ColumnConstraints();
        rightCol.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);

        controls.getColumnConstraints().addAll(leftCol, rightCol);

        GridPane.setHalignment(controls, HPos.LEFT);
        GridPane.setHalignment(totalLabel, HPos.LEFT);

        controls.setHgap(5);
        controls.setVgap(5);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table, null, null, controls, null);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private List<Trade> createData() {
        Random rng = new Random();
        List<Trade> trades = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            StringBuilder name = new StringBuilder();
            for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
                name.append(Character.toString((char)(rng.nextInt(26)+'A')));
            }
            double price = rng.nextInt(100000)/100.0 ;
            int volume = rng.nextInt(10000);
            trades.add(new Trade(name.toString(), volume, price));
        }
        return trades ;
    }

    private <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> column(String text, Function<S, ObservableValue<T>> property) {
        TableColumn<S,T> col = new TableColumn<>(text);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        return col ;
    }

    public static class Trade {
        private final String name ;
        private final IntegerProperty volume = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        private final DoubleProperty price = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        private final ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper total = new ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper();

        public Trade(String name, int volume, double price) {
            this.name = name ;
            setPrice(price);
            setVolume(volume);
            total.bind(priceProperty().multiply(volumeProperty()));
        }

        public final String getName() {
            return name ;
        }

        public final IntegerProperty volumeProperty() {
            return this.volume;
        }

        public final int getVolume() {
            return this.volumeProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setVolume(final int volume) {
            this.volumeProperty().set(volume);
        }

        public final DoubleProperty priceProperty() {
            return this.price;
        }

        public final double getPrice() {
            return this.priceProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setPrice(final double price) {
            this.priceProperty().set(price);
        }

        public final ReadOnlyDoubleProperty totalProperty() {
            return this.total.getReadOnlyProperty();
        }

        public final double getTotal() {
            return this.totalProperty().get();
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: The first method you proposed works. Do not know why the second method you proposed does not work, as I managed to compile and run the code but the `sumOfTotals` always return 0.

Comment: Interesting. I will find out myself where my bug is. Thanks.

Comment: The first one worked, now my table is updating the sums. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

Since both current price and volume held are properties, you could just bind them directly:

```
total.bind(currentPriceProperty().multiply(volumeHeldProperty()));
```

If you absolutely need to use a custom double binding, you first need to provide dependencies so that the computation is performed once the dependencies become invalidated as per [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/DoubleBinding.html):

```
DoubleBinding totalBinding = new DoubleBinding() {

     {
         super.bind(currentPrice, volumeHeld);
     }

     @Override
     protected double computeValue() {
         return currentPrice.get() * volumeHeld.get();
     }
 };
```

The following helper function provided by `Bindings` should also work:

```
DoubleBinding totalBinding = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() ->
        currentPrice.get() * volumeHeld.get(),
        currentPrice, volumeHeld);
```

Comment: so `currentPrice.get()` works but the `getCurrentPrice()` instance method I wrote does not ?

Comment: I have added the details about the second part of my question, explaining how it fails.

Comment: Note that in the answer, when using `Bindings.createDoubleBinding(...)`, additional arguments are provided to the method, indicating the properties that need to be observed. (The binding needs to know what to observe in order to know when it has to update itself.)

Comment: @James_D Yes, you are absolutely right. I observed that, and I tried to put `total` as the second arguments and this failed because the second part of my questions is actually trying to work out the sum of the `total` property of each Trade object, and this method actually sits  in a different class.